# Get returned message using CURL-GET submission

Tags: php, json, curl, get

I would like to store the returned JSON message from the url below into a variable of somesort using PHP.

Inside my controller i have this code:

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.livepicly.com/app/api.php'.$str);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

($str is a variable that contains all the required parameters).

The said URL:

http://www.livepicly.com/app/api.php?method=add_reservation&email=jbond%40example.com&fname=James&lname=Bond&phone=1234561&vid=726&size=2&date=2013-05-31+1%3A15+PM&request=Hi+there

(When the above url is opened, it will return a JSON message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.livepicly.com/app/api.php'.$str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$my_array = json_decode($data,true);  // <-- turns the returned json into an assoc array
$my_obj =  json_decode($data); // <-- or into an object

// {"foo-bar": 12345}
echo $my_array['foo-bar'];   // outputs 12345
echo $my_obj->{'foo-bar'};  // outputs 12345
```

Comment: thx for reminding this part $my_array = json_decode($data,true); i've been trying without the true param.

Comment: Nice cleaner response within the decode, noticed you initially forgot the "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER" though :P

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to return the transfer.

```
<?php

$str = '?method=add_reservation&email=jbond%40example.com&fname=James&lname=Bond&phone=1234561&vid=726&size=2&date=2013-05-31+1%3A15+PM&request=Hi+there';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.livepicly.com/app/api.php'.$str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($result);
var_dump($result->result[0]->message);

?>
```